# MPEG-TS audio synchronization lost on segmentation

Tags: http, streaming

I use FFmpeg for encoding my iphone video (on debian) and mediafilesegmenter (on mac OS server).  For encoding this is my commande :

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT -y  -acodec libfaac -ar 22000 -ab 40k -vcodec libx264 -b 600k  \
-bt 600k -vpre slow -vpre baseline -threads 1 -level 30 -r 10 -s 400x224 \
-map_chapters -1:-1 -f ipod INPUT.mp4
```

When i read the INPUT.mp4 everything is OK with audio.
But when I use the Apple Segmenter (mediafilesegmenter) i have a descync between audio & video.

Is my command line is wrong ? or it's a Apple segmenter bug. The mediastreamvalidator show me :

> WARNING: Media segment contains a video track but does not contain any IDR access unit with a SPS and a PPS

But i don't know if cause the audio desync.

I have the latest mediafilesegmenter download from connect.apple.com.